# Is Quiet connected?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

Is Quiet the

> assassin at the beginning of the game in the hospital room?

Kaz makes reference to it during

> her torture scene

But doesnt follow up on it.

They have the same build and it is possible with his theory?

So is it her?

Answer (score 2):

Spoilers ahoy, although not a major one:

> Yes it's her at the beginning.
>  The reason she went under parasite treatment, it was due to the heavy >! injuries she suffered from that event, which she almost died from.

Comment: Please edit your comment and format it for spoilers

Comment: @sommerjj Spoilers are not a requirement.  If you're looking at a question, you should be expecting to get spoiled.

Comment: Dude as much as I get what youre saying in your answer, although you are basically saying what Kaz said in different words, can you back this up, sources or anything?

Comment: Well, there is her biography at the metal gear wiki, 

http://metalgear.wikia.com/wiki/Quiet

Comment: @Foxhound Try replaying the hospital mission and looking at her face :P It's pretty clearly her.